# Android apache poi edit numeric cell

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I am using apache poi in an Android application and I try to edit a numeric cell to make empty or null.

I looked for information on the internet but I found nothing interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways of achieving this.

1) Remove the cell by calling [`removeCell` on the `Row`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#removeCell%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) containing the `Cell`.  This will also remove any formatting or styling on the cell.

```
row.removeCell(cellToMakeEmpty);
```

2) Set the cell's cell type to `CELL_TYPE_BLANK` with [`Cell`'s `setCellType` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29).  That will clear any value on the cell, but it leaves formatting and styling intact.

```
cellToMakeEmpty.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you should HSSFDataFormat object to change style format something like that ;

```
public void setStyleFormat(int dataType, HSSFCellStyle styleRow, Workbook wb) {
    HSSFDataFormat df = (HSSFDataFormat) wb.createDataFormat();
    switch (dataType) {
    case Types.DATE:
    case Types.TIME:
    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
        styleRow.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("m/d/yy"));
        break;
    case Types.INTEGER:
    case Types.NUMERIC:
    case Types.DECIMAL:
        styleRow.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("0"));
        break;
    default:
        styleRow.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("@"));
        break;
    }
}
```